# show which scripts are loaded

Tags: javascript

I have a suspicion some users have toolbars, plugins, malware or something, which is running some javascript in their browser when visiting our site, and this javascript is messing up the functions on our pages.

Can my javascript see which javascripts have been loaded from other files, i.e. by http://some.site/script.js'> ?

Answer (score 0):

Open the developer tools on your browser (usually with F12). Then check the network section/tab, it will list all resources loaded into the current document.

Comment: I think @LeifNeland wants to find scripts on remote machines.  Your answer will work only if you are sitting at the machine you are checking.

Comment: It should be detected either serverside, or showing in the customers browser. "Hey, our shop can not work properly, because your browser is infected by malware from www.superfish.com. This malware will xxxx. Please do yyy to remove the infection."

Comment: So you'll first have to identify the culprits, then add some js to detect the changes they're doing.

Comment: Difficult to identify culprits beforehand, I only get boss-calls "Site is not working again!?" Would be nice to just see which scripts were loaded which are not ours.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find scripts loaded by a page and you are not able to access the dev tools, you can search the DOM for script tags.  This will only find scripts that were loaded by the DOM (which is quite typical). But it will not find scripts loaded through xhr requests and then eval-ed and it will not find scripts loaded by browser extensions.

But, this may still help you somewhat.  You can do something like this:

```
console.log(window.document.getElementsByTagName("script"))
```

This will log all loaded scripts to the console.  Alternatively, you can analyze this in the client and pop up a bright big warning message if you see something suspicious.

To capture other kinds of requests, you might be able to add a wrapper to the xhr send method, like this:

```
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function () {
  // do some checking of the request
  // do the actual request
  this.send();
}
```

I haven't tried this, so there may be some caveats, like I'm not sure if all browser engines allow you to redefine methods of built-in types.  But it is worth trying out.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is interesting but the motivation is wrong, IMO. What leads you to believe that "something" is messing up your JavaScript? Can you reproduce the issue? Even if some kind of bookmarklet is clobbering global JavaScript code, you (as a developer) have the ability to check for proper functionality and polyfill if needed.

If you look more closely at your code and why it's not doing what you expect, I expect that you're going to find that malware/toolbars/plugins are the not to blame.

Isolate the code that is failing and reproduce the behavior.